# Fetching data from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asynchronous, request

I've got some troubles fetching data from JSON array. I'm using node + async + request (and express ofc).

Part of the code :

```
 function(data, callback){
                var URL = 'https://'+ server + '.api.pvp.net/api/lol/' + serw + '/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' + data.id + '/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' + api;
                request(URL, function(err, response, body){
                    if(!err & response.statusCode == 200){
                        var json = JSON.parse(body);
                        var assists = json['playerStatSummaries'][0]['aggregatedStats'].totalAssists;
```

The main problem is that [0] is giving back the first object from array.

```
{
   "playerStatSummaries": [
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType": "CAP5x5",
         "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 2042,
            "totalMinionKills": 4317,
            "totalChampionKills": 350,
            "totalAssists": 417,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 36
         },
         "modifyDate": 1453276061000,
         "wins": 20
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType": "CoopVsAI",
         "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 446,
            "totalMinionKills": 6100,
            "totalChampionKills": 1092,
            "totalAssists": 761,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 116
         },
         "modifyDate": 1453276061000,
         "wins": 80
      },
```

Sometimes the array is a bit different and if player haven't played any "CAP5x5" game, the COOPvsAI is the [0] object.

> Any ideas how to fetch data by it's playerStatSummaryType instead of object number in array?
>    Or how to make some kind of bypass that makes null when can't find "CAP5x5" mode? Thanks.

Comment: What to you want to get out?

Comment: var assists = json['playerStatSummaries'][0]['aggregatedStats'].totalAssists; Gives me totalAssists of 1 object in the array and i want to get out totalAssists but without using [0], because sometimes if player hasn't played this mode the [0] is something totally different and it's not giving back data that i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filterOnPlayerStatSummary(myObject, filter)
{
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) 
    {
        if (myObject[i].playerStatSummary == filter)
        { 
            result.push(myObject[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ES2015, the following will work

```
let json = JSON.parse(body);
let assists = json
   .playerStatSummaries
   .filter((a) => a.playerStatSummaryType =='CAP5x5')
   .map((a) => a.aggregatedStats.totalAssists)
   .reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
```